# RDB2RDF Approaches

Tags: etl, semantic-web

I read this [W3C-Description](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/RDB2RDF) of the two different approaches for RDB2RDF.

The ETL approach is pretty clear to me.

But I'm not sure if I did understand the "Virtual Mapping" approach. Is it a direct translation of SPARQL queries to SQL queries without any mapping file, or is virtual mapping using [Direct Mapping](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdb-direct-mapping/) (with/without) a mapping file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mapping has to be involved. Let it be the Direct Mapping (the default mapping of relational data to RDF) or a custome mapping written by somebody in R2RML.

With the mapping, you can do two things:

- ETL: extract the relational data, transform to RDF per the mapping, so it can then be loaded into a triplestore
- NoETL (the "virtual mapping" approach): view the relational database as if it were a triplestore which means that SPARQL queries are translated into SQL queries per the mapping

Comment: That means you need a mapping file for 'virtual mapping' or is it optional?

Comment: You always need a mapping. Let it be the default mapping which is the Direct Mapping, or a customized mapping in R2RML.

Answer (score 3):

The wording here is indeed weird. The ETL approach means that you convert entire dataset into triples.

From the link document I understand that the Virtual Mapping is indeed an approach, where you translate SPARQL into SQL queries and run the latter directly on the source database.

Comment: So that means ETL is an approach to materialize and Virtual Mapping is an approach to access a relational DB via SPARQL? :)

Comment: Yes. That's how I understand what the page says. Not sure why it uses term "virtual mapping" TBH

Comment: I agree. I often see the term 'virtual' when I read about RDB2RDF - and it's often used differently :/ e.g. The d2rq Mapper creates virtual graphs... but they're materialized (concrete files on the hdd).